# How to randomize objects?

Tags: modeling

So i created a basic low poly grass model. How can i apply it onto another mesh, possibly a ground plane. Is there a technique to scatter it randomly on the plane?

[image]

Comment: [Why not look up your question on Youtube?](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=create+grass+with+particles) There are literally hundreds of tutorials on how to do this exact thing.

Comment: Yes it is possibIe, you should look up Particle systems. I feel this is a valid question. While it is easy to find answers when you know what you are looking for (particles and particle systems), there could be more in-depth already answered questions on BSE.